# javafx8 timeline - how to get the source of the animation

Tags: animation, lambda, javafx-8, timeline

I want to have 3 objects doing different things, so I want to get the source of the caller.
I am using lambda for that, and I am not using key frame, the animation is the same and cyclic so I don't need to specify different behavior for a different key frame.

Maybe I am doing something wrong with the lambda?

this is my code:

```
class MyClock extends ClockPane //clockpane extends pane
    {
         Timeline animation;            
        int id;

        EventHandler<ActionEvent> eventHandler = e -> 
        {//startAnimationById();
        System.out.println(e.getSource()==clockControl1.myclock.animation);
        };

        public MyClock(int c,int id)    
        {
            super(c);

            this.id=id;         
            animation = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(1000),eventHandler));
            animation.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
            animation.play();
        }
```

the startanimationbyid method works using the id I defined to avoid this problem, but it surely does bug me.

I have 3 different objects of this type, each one is nested ina clockcontrol class 
(in other words I have clockcontrol1 clockcontrol2 and 3 each one of these having a MyClock myclock in them)

The print I have there returns false for all the the clocks I have (total of 3) while as it is currently written I'd expect to get true for the first clock...I tried different variations of this, the one I post here is only the last variation, but I got false for all of my attempts.

Where did I mess things up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [API for `KeyFrame`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/KeyFrame.html#getOnFinished--) doesn't specify what the source of the `ActionEvent` will be. You could just do `System.out.println(e.getSource())` to see (it seems that the source of the event is the `KeyFrame` object, not the animation), but there's no real guarantee it would always be what you expect.

If you want different instances of `MyClock` to behave differently, you can provide a parameter for the different behavior. In this case, you could use a `Runnable` to execute different code in the event handler:

```
class MyClock extends ClockPane //clockpane extends pane
    {
         Timeline animation;            
        // int id;




        public MyClock(int c, Runnable handler)    
        {
            super(c);

            EventHandler<ActionEvent> eventHandler = e -> handler.run() ;

            animation = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(1000),eventHandler));
            animation.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
            animation.play();
        }
}
```

Then you can instantiate these as you need:

```
public class Controller1 {

    // ...

    MyClock clock = new MyClock(..., () -> {
        // code to execute for this clock
    });
}
```

and

```
public class Controller2 {

    // ...
    MyClock clock = new MyClock(..., () -> {
        // code to execute for this clock
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it seems a good solution to the problem I presented given its structure.

I came up with a better solution to my specific problem.
Though not as generic, but it is good enough for my needs.

I changed the Animation to this:

    animation = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(1000),ev ->startAnimation()));

And the method itself is:
       private void startAnimation()
   { 
    if(this.getParent()==clockControl1)
     ...
}

Comment: That doesn't seem very maintainable, but OK.